# How to flatten innermost array

Tags: ruby

I have this array:

```
[[["a", "c"], "e"],
 [["a", "c"], "f"],
 [["a", "c"], "g"],
 [["a", "d"], "e"],
 [["a", "d"], "f"],
 [["a", "d"], "g"],
 [["b", "c"], "e"],
 [["b", "c"], "f"],
 [["b", "c"], "g"],
 [["b", "d"], "e"],
 [["b", "d"], "f"],
 [["b", "d"], "g"]]
```

I would like to turn it into this:

```
[["a", "c", "e"],
 ["a", "c", "f"],
 ["a", "c", "g"],
 ["a", "d", "e"],
 ["a", "d", "f"],
 ["a", "d", "g"],
 ["b", "c", "e"],
 ["b", "c", "f"],
 ["b", "c", "g"],
 ["b", "d", "e"],
 ["b", "d", "f"],
 ["b", "d", "g"]]
```

How can I do this with Ruby?  I have looked at flatten by it seems to work from the outside in, not inside out.

Comment: You might want to look into why you're getting the array in the first form rather than the second. When I see data in the first form it's usually because I did something wrong and need to rethink my code.

Comment: @theTinMan, good point.  I am getting the data in that form as a result of the product call.  I'll post the call syntax to show how it was generated.

Comment: That works. Often we see questions dealing with a symptom as someone seeks a bandage, when the real problem needs a bit of refactoring or a different approach which ends up fixing a lot of other code.

Comment: @theTinMan, I created a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286499/how-to-create-permutation-of-an-array-using-values-from-sub-arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

or try `arr.each {|i| i.flatten!}`

Comment: That depends on whether you want a destructive or a non-destructive version. OMG's answer is a non-destructive one.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, but op said "I would like to turn it into this", so i think the original won't be needed

Comment: Thanks, I chose this one cause I don't need the original.  I wish I could give half a check to both answers.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: @JoshPetitt If you don’t need original then you can use also `ar.map! {|i| i.flatten}`. It will destroy the original one.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) and [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
ar.map! {|i| i.flatten}
 # => [["a", "c", "e"],
 #     ["a", "c", "f"],
 #     ["a", "c", "g"],
 #     ["a", "d", "e"],
 #     ["a", "d", "f"],
 #     ["a", "d", "g"],
 #     ["b", "c", "e"],
 #     ["b", "c", "f"],
 #     ["b", "c", "g"],
 #     ["b", "d", "e"],
 #     ["b", "d", "f"],
 #     ["b", "d", "g"]]
```

Another *one-liner* would be :

```
 ar.map!(&:flatten)

 # => [["a", "c", "e"],
 #     ["a", "c", "f"],
 #     ["a", "c", "g"],
 #     ["a", "d", "e"],
 #     ["a", "d", "f"],
 #     ["a", "d", "g"],
 #     ["b", "c", "e"],
 #     ["b", "c", "f"],
 #     ["b", "c", "g"],
 #     ["b", "d", "e"],
 #     ["b", "d", "f"],
 #     ["b", "d", "g"]]
```

Comment: Note `&:flatten` requires at least Ruby 1.9.3 or a similar version.

Comment: @JanDvorak Should I mention it in the post,that's why I have given two forms of answers.

Comment: Adding version information in the answer is always nice. "Since 1.x.x, you can also do \n..."